# Gradle Jaxb Plugin Issue

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb

I am trying to generate classes from multiple `.xsd`s in gradle. Tried like below, but it does not work and i get error that `file not exists`.

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6")
}
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

configurations {
    jaxb
}

task createDirs {
    file("$buildDir/generated-sources").mkdirs()
}
xjc.dependsOn createDirs

jaxb {
    xsdDir = "src/main/resources/xsd"
    xjc {
        destinationDir = "$buildDir/generated-sources"
        taskClassname = "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task"
        generatePackage = "com.test.generated1"
        args = ["-Xinheritance", "-Xannotate"]
    }
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn(xjc)
}

compileTestJava {
    dependsOn(xjc)
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    jaxb('org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-ant:0.6.5')
    jaxb('org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:0.6.4')
    jaxb('org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-annotate:0.6.4')
    jaxb('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7-b41')
    jaxb('com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41')
}
```

If i remove `destinationDir = file("build/generated-sources")`, it generates classes inside `src/main/java` which i do not want.

I get error `.../build/generated-sources: non-existent directory`

Any help is appreciated :)

**NOTE: Gradle Version 3.2.1**

Comment: Try using a variable for build directory `"$buildDir/generated-sources"`

Comment: change jaxb.dependsOn to xjc.dependsOn as xjc is the actual task

Comment: this brings the `Execution failed for task ':xjc'. ..../build/generated-sources: non-existent directory` error back

Comment: that's weird it works I just tried it...

Comment: Maybe its my gradle version or something ? I am using 3.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a variable for build directory `"$buildDir/generated-sources"`

Like vampire noticed you need to create the directory first.

I would suggest creating a task for it with `doFirst()` which will execute sooner on the execution phase.

```
task createDirs {
    doFirst{
        file("$buildDir/generated-sources").mkdirs()
    }
}
```

and then run if before xjc:

```
xjc.dependsOn createDirs
```

And in this task particular task try to just pass the raw `/build` path because it seems like `destinationDir` already points to the root. Not sure what is going on here. Other than that I strongly sugest usign the variables `$buildDir`

```
jaxb {
    xsdDir = "src/main/resources/xsd"
    xjc {
        destinationDir = "build/generated-sources"
        taskClassname = "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task"
        generatePackage = "com.test.generated1"
        args = ["-Xinheritance", "-Xannotate"]
    }
}
```

Another thing is you could watch on the directory changes if you don't want to run expensive xjc task all the time.

```
xjc {
    inputs.dir ("$projectDir/src/main/resources/xsd")
    outputs.dir ("$buildDir/generated-sources")
}
```

Comment: I think i should go for different plugin. I would write the task myself, but just starting gradle so, not much idea

Comment: have you created a task to create dirs ?

Comment: yes of course. I will modify question and add those

Comment: "and the task doesn't need `$buildDir` as `destinationDir` points to the root in the first place, then adding it would add another full path at the end" is non-sense. You should **never** hard-code `'build'`. If you or any future developer ever decides he does not like `build` as `buildDir` but something else, it simply works for all places if you used the variable, but not if you hard-coded the path. Hard-coded stuff is always bad if you have respective variables.

Comment: @Vampire I agree i always try to use variables, but this one `destinationDir` if i used it with the variable gave me `C:/<myWholePath>/C:/<myWholePath>/build` and using `build/` in this particular place solved the problem ?

Comment: @LazerBanana ah well, then I'd say the plugin is badly implemented and you should open an improvement request to them. In the meantime you can do something like `destinationDir = "${project.relativePath(project.buildDir).replace('\\', '/')}/generated-sources"`

Answer (score 0):

One point is that you should use the variable `buildDir` instead of using hard-coded `'build'`.

That's not your problem though. Your problem is, that the plugin you are using does not create a non-existent target directory. So add the creation action to the task like

```
jaxb {
    doFirst {
        file("$buildDir/generated-sources").mkdirs()
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer, create a separate task that does only the directory creation and then add a dependency from `jaxb` to your directory creation task.

Comment: that's weird my project does not need to mkdir on this one, I was thinking this might be the problem but do you need to use file() here as well? I just created a dummy project and it accepts a string as a path without creating it before.

Comment: Hm, ok, I never used that plugin, I just assumed about its behavior from the effect described